# Rewrite_time in _search takes a lot longer after upgrading from 6.4.2 to 6.8.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.8

I have asked this on the Elasticsearch forum already, so I'm cross sharing here in case anyone has some ideas.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rewrite-time-in-search-takes-a-lot-longer-after-upgrading-from-6-4-2-to-6-8-2/196960